# event.preventDefault() does not work in Chrome and Opera

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery Validation Plugin 1.9.0 with jQuery 1.7.2.

I want my form to be validated with jquery validation plugin.
It works fine in Firefox 20.0.1 and IE 10.
But in Chrome (26.0.1410.64 m) and in Opera (12.14) I cannot click on cancel in my form without preventing validation to be done.

This is my javascript code:

```
 submitHandler: function(form) {
  if (this.submitButton.value != 'cancel') {
   $(form).hide();
   $('#load').show();
   $(form).submit();
  }
  else {
  event.preventDefault();
  }
 }
```

When I click on cancel on FF and IE I go back to my web home page as expected, but when I do this in Chrome and Opera my error messages are displayed as the form is incompletely filled.
In both case the event.preventDefault() is called but it seems the behavior is different depending on the navigator.

Do you have any idea of what may be wrong ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: If you don't actually define `event` anywhere, you can't prevent it's default action.

Comment: event is defined on window (hence, just calling event.preventDefault() will be like calling window.event.preventDefault() - if event hasn't already been defined in a higher lexical scope - and it should still work). I think the real problem is that the OP doesn't understand what event.preventDefault() means.

Comment: Show your HTML.  Otherwise, we can't help you very well.

Comment: @Adam: That "feature" is being phased out.  Not all browsers support it, so it's *not* recommended that you use `window.event`.

Comment: `submitHandler`, when set, will prevent the form from being submitted.  `preventDefault` is not needed here, you're not in an event.  So, unless you call `form.submit()`, nothing will be submitted.

Comment: What is your "cancel" button supposed to do?

Comment: Thanks for your explanations!
The cancel button was supposed to go to home page without applying validation rules.
The html looks like this:

    <form id='contact' action='contact.php' method='post'>
      <input type='submit' name='envoyer' id='envoyer'/>
      <input type='submit' class='cancel' name='annuler' id='annuler' value='annuler'/>
    </form>
When I clicked on cancel button, it tries to validate form anyway and does not send the form content to contact.php (which would detect cancel button was pressed and go back home).
That is why I tried to play with preventDefault...

Comment: In deed I forgot the $(form).submit() in the post, I just added it again ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the purpose of `.preventDefault()`.  It's not meant for preventing the default behavior of a function.  It's meant for canceling the built-in behaviors of regular elements, i.e., remove the navigation and history from an anchor tag, etc.

See: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

AFAIK, you cannot programatically turn validation on and off.  Once you initialize the plugin with `.validate()`, there is no method to "un"-initialize it.

However, to simply use a "cancel" button, there are several methods...  one is to make sure you keep the cancel button *outside* of the `<form></form>` and then use a `click` handler to do something else with it.

**DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/TZVA6/1

Or another method, as pointed out by Rocket Hazmat, is to give the `button` a `type="button"` attribute which prevents the default `submit` action.

**DEMO**:  http://jsfiddle.net/TZVA6/2/

Comment: You can put the cancel button inside the `<form>`.  Just give it `type="button"`, otherwise it's defaulted to a "submit" button.  http://jsfiddle.net/TZVA6/2/

Comment: @RocketHazmat, yes, that is definitely another way.